# очистка значений комбобоксов

Tags: javascript, html, combobox

У меня есть несколько комбобоксов, в которых при загрузке страницы отражается первый элемент списка select. В процессе работы пользователь меняет значения комбобоксов, затем нажимает кнопку "проверить", получает результат и переходит к новой задаче на этой же странице (решение новой задачи он записывает в эти же комбобоксы). Поскольку страница не обновляется, в комбобоксах остаются ранее выбранные значения, и при решении новой задачи это несколько напрягает.
Можно ли с помощью JavaScript внутри функции обратиться ко всем комбобоксам (например, по их ID) и "обнулить" их значения (то есть вернуть в окно комбобокса первое значение из списка)?
Пробовал сделать так:

```
function cBoxesCleaner(){
    let answer1 = document.getElementById("cBox1").innerHTML;
    answer1.value = "-"; // символ "-" является первым значением всех комбобоксов
    let answer2 = document.getElementById("cBox2").innerHTML;
    answer2.value = "-";
}
```

К сожалению, не сработало.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно решить проблему?

Comment: у innerHTML нет свойства value и никогда не было.... а вот у элемента - да

Answer (score 1):

Уберите innerHTML и заработает.

```
function cBoxesCleaner(){
    let answer1 = document.getElementById("cBox1");
    answer1.value = "-";
    let answer2 = document.getElementById("cBox2");
    answer2.value = "-";
}
```

Для выбора нужного вам варианта в select необходимо изменить value на значение value выбираемого элемента. Если у элемента `value="1"`, то для выбора этого варианта сделайте так: `select.value = "1"`

```js
const select = document.querySelector(".select");
const button = document.querySelector(".button");

button.addEventListener('click', () => {
  select.value = "1";
})
```

```html
<select class="select">
  <option value=" ">-</option>
  <option value="1">вар1</option>
  <option value="2">вар2</option>
</select>

<button class="button">Эта кнопка задаёт select.value="1"</button>
```

Comment: Спасибо! К сожалению, эффект не тот.  Идея в том, чтобы вернуть отображаемое значение к первому значению из списка:
```
<td><select class="cBox" id="cBox1" onchange=getUserAnswer()>
                        <option value=" ">-</option>
                        <option value="1)"> вар1 </option>
                        <option value="2"> вар2 </option>
                        </select></td>
```
Т.е. пользователем был выбран вар2, а после загрузки нового задания в окне комбобокса вар2 менялся на пробел

Comment: Для того чтобы был выбран первый элемент изменяйте value на то, которое у первого элемента. Например, в коде который вы прислали value = " " (value равен пробелу), тогда для выбора этого элемента в select необходимо сделать так: answer2.value = " ";

Answer (score 0):

Огромное спасибо, Logos! Ваш вариант сработал, но есть одно существенное дополнение. Чекбоксов было 5, им был присвоен класс "cBox". Интересно, что при нажатии на кнопку значение менялось только у первого чекбокса. Пришлось добавить им еще один класс (свой для каждого из пяти ответов) и продублировать код с учётом всех пяти классов. В итоге рабочий вариант выглядит примерно так (чтобы не писать лишнего, оставил 2 чекбокса):
HTML:

```
<select class="cBox Mult" onchange=getUserD()>
<option value=" ">-</option>
<option value="вар1"> вариант1 </option>
<option value="вар2"> вариант2 </option>
</select>

<select class="cBox Nos" onchange=getUserD()>
<option value=" ">-</option>
<option value="вар2"> вариант1 </option>
<option value="вар2"> вариант2 </option>
</select>
```

JavaScript:

```
const select1 = document.querySelector(".Mult");
const select2 = document.querySelector(".Nos");

button.addEventListener('click', () => {
  select1.value = " ";
  select2.value = " ";
})
```